# AngularJS data binding with passed parameter

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

Form:

```
<form novalidate name="form" ng-submit="addArticle(newPost)">
    <textarea ng-model="newPost.content" required></textarea>
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid">
</form>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('StreamDetailCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.newPost = {};

    $scope.addArticle = function(newPost) {
        // [Post stuff to server]

        // Clear form
        newPost = {};
    };
});
```

The problem here is that the form isn't cleared, there is no data binding going on. Obviously if I would do `$scope.newPost = {};` inside the method it works fine, but I can't use that (the real code has this addArticle method inside a different service, so I need to pass the newPost to it).

How can I bind this `newPost` parameter so that changing it changes my form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try either:

- `newPost.content = null`, if you only want to clear this property
- `angular.copy({}, newPost)` will clear *everything* inside `newPost` (if you want to clean all properties)